# Loading resources in Spring Boot application from internal jar file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

We are getting the following error in a special scheduling server Spring Book application. This application is a jar file that runs on a server and includes all the server jars from our web application in it to run the same types of jobs that could be triggered through the UI application.

The problem is that in the UI Web Application the main server jar has some files in the resources directory that have no problems in the Main server Spring Boot application running on its own. The scheduler application therefore has the server.jar file where in it has the resources directory. The scheduler.jar file has the server.jar in it. So when I try to get the file out of the server.jar resources directory I get the following error, it is thrown in the exact same code that runs find in the web application.

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [reports/specialResource/template.pdf] cannot be opened because it does not exist

I just changed the code to

```
String src = "classpath:reports/specialResource/template.pdf";
InputStream inputStream = resourceLoader.getResource(src).getInputStream();
```

Which didn't work. Thanks.

Comment: Can you add the exact path of PDF inside the jar? Is it server.jar/reports/specialResource/template.pdf? or server.jar/resources/reports/specialResource/template.pdf?

Comment: Thanks for responding K. I ended up copying the pdf and the 2 .jasper files I needed into the module's resources directory. So if they ever are changed in the application, I need to make sure I copy the new versions there too. It works, but a hack. Good thing those reports and pdf should change very rarely.